# How to disable or protect against disposable email accounts?

Tags: user-registration

Now im getting a couple of disposable email accounts in users table, how can I avoid this nasty situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/no-disposable-email/

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the `register_post` action hook, and pass the email address through `is_email()`, to which you can add a filter to disallow the characters (such as "+" used to create disposable email addresses).

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would add to this answer as none was specified and it took me a while to find a solution.

What I am using is the blacklist method where you specify a list to block. It works well as users just give up after trying the biggest disposable email providers.

The code can be found here: [How to Block Disposable Email Addresses: PHP Code](http://www.articlevoid.com/computers-and-technology/coding/how-to-block-disposable-email-addresses/)

It works by letting you create an array of domains you which to block. You then provide an email address as a variable and this gets split to get the domain. This is compared to the list and as you can see on the website you can do whatever you like if a disposable email is detected.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

please also have a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/block-disposable-email-addresses/ which is a plugin for wordpress that uses http://www.block-disposable-email.com/

Best regards,

Gerold

Comment: [You must disclose your affiliation in your answers.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)